# Volvo V40 wont start, red led light on speaker flashes rapidly

Tags: starting, volvo, immobilizer

My Volvo V40 will not start. When I put the key to position 2, the red LED light on the left speaker on the dash flashes rapidly for 15 seconds. When I turn the key to position 3 the lights on the dash clocks go off. No crank, no start, nothing. [This is a youtube video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV_HIDz-Xc8) .

Comment: I would bet this is the security system in the car. I don't know exactly how the Volvo system works, but would bet either the key has lost its registration with the vehicle (try a second key if you have it), or the security system itself is broke (such as the key reader ... if so equipped). Can you please supply the year of the vehicle so we might be able to help you further?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. It's a 2001 Volvo V40. 1948cc engine. I have 2 keys and it's the same when I try both.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the immobilizer.